# Как найти центр фигуры?

Tags: javascript, canvas, геометрия

Функция, находящая центр фигуры уже есть. Но похоже, она работает не правильно.
Вот она:

```
function center() {
  var count = 0, // Число точек
    allx = 0, // Сумма координат всех точек по оси x
    ally = 0, // Сумма координат всех точек по оси y
    seg = poly.segments; // массив точек
  for (var i = 0; i < seg.length; i++) {
    allx += seg[i][0];
    ally += seg[i][1];
    count++;
  }
  return [allx / count, ally / count]; // Центр фигуры - [x, y]
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xm2x8jaa/)

Почему при вращении многоугольника вокруг своего центра точка, возвращаемая функцией, тоже вращается? Как можно исправить функцию?

Comment: а относительно чего вы вращаете фигуру?

Comment: похоже что вокруг центра - настоящего ;-))

Comment: Вокруг центра..

Comment: вот возьмите ту точку вокруг которой вращается в качестве центра, а глючный код который находит черную точку утилизируйте ;-)

Comment: неужели не видно что находит какую-то ерунду а не центр

Comment: `const center = () => return [poly.x, poly.y];`

Comment: @Eugene Bartosh: Прекрасно видно, что находит не "ерунду", а именно *центр*, но "притянутый" в сторону одной из исходных вершин. Это сразу же наводит на мысль о том, что именно произошло. Далее см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как несложно догадаться, ваш `poly.toLine();` формирует ломаную линию "полигон", в которой первая точка ломаной еще раз повторена в конце ломаной. При этом для пятиугольника ломаная будет состоять из 6 точек, а не из 5 (`seg.length` будет возвращать 6, а не 5). Таким образом в вашем цикле усреднения одна из точек пятиугольника (первая) участвует два раза и тем самым "оттягивает" результат усреднения на себя.

Исправьте цикл, например, так

```
for (var i = 1; i < seg.length; i++) {
```

и вычисленный центр будет действительно центром.

https://jsfiddle.net/txqb641f/

Answer (score 1):

вращение всегда будет выглядеть эстетично, если вращать вокруг этой точки `((minx+maxx)/2,(miny+maxy)/2)`, где minx, miny, maxx, maxy - максимальные и минимальные координаты всех вершин, точку только не надо перерасчитывать в процессе вращения

Answer (score -1):

Замените свою функцию center на эту:

```
const center = () => [-poly2.radius / 1.18, 0];
```